# editText view not minding layout_width

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a layout problem. I have three editText views in a table row. They each have the same attributes, but the first two of them will not mind the layout_width I have set. 
NOTE: the hints each have the same amount of characters.

ANSWER: Removed table and used nested linear layouts.

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowQuad1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextQuadA"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:hint="@string/hintA" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextQuadB"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:hint="@string/hintB" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextQuadC"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:hint="@string/hintC" />

    </TableRow>
```

editTextQuadC shows the correct width, but A and B stay the same size unless I make it larger than they appear. They seem to appear about 75-85 sp. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change tableRow to LinearLayout and try it work fine as below::

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRowQuad1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextQuadA"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:hint="@string/hintA" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextQuadB"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:hint="@string/hintB" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextQuadC"
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                android:hint="@string/hintC" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

since if you use table row it is dependent other table row for its width.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even think about other rows in my table. This worked liked a charm. Thanks again.